# Vim load buffer depending on file type

Tags: vim

I am using vim for a lot of languages and I am hoping to improve the `ctrl + p/n` autocomplete. When I am going to work with a specific one I load a file in the buffer containing the substet of language specific functions I am using like so:

```
:badd perl.txt
```

This loads the functions inside that file to the `auto-complete buffer`
I have one `.txt` file for each language I am using. I wish to automate this process by having a particular buffer loaded depending on the file type. I tried searching but cloudn't find a good answer. The only lead I have is that I might need to use `filetype plugins` thought not sure how. Bonus points (though not important) if the solution is just in the rc file (since it will be easy to set up new work places that way)

One possible solution:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *`<extention>` badd `<dir to file>`
```

Example:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *pl badd /home/vim_autocomplete/perl.txt
```

Comment: Can't you just use seperate autocmd for every lagnguage you use? I hope it is a finite set. You could write a function that checks whether a file has been already loaded to avoid multiple buffadds.

Comment: I like the idea. I am new to vim (2-3 weeks of usage) and I had no idea that such a thing existed. I will look into it.

Comment: Here is quite nice explanation with filetypes too. http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html

Comment: @Dārayavahuštdi -- add your comment as an answer and I'll upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question you asked, I think that

```
:au FileType * badd path/to/<amatch>.txt
```

(untested) will work.  Instead of using `:badd`, I would modify the `'complete'` option:

```
:au FileType * setl complete+=k/path/to/<amatch>.txt
```

Either way, you can wrap the command in a test:

```
:au FileType * if filereadable("path/to/<amatch>.txt") | ... | endif
```

(equally untested).  Of course, if you want a single autocommand, then (whichever approach you use) you will have to name the files after the file types.

```
:help :au
:help FileType
:help <amatch>
:help 'complete'
```

Comment: I found my own way of doing it (edited the first post) however it would not have been possible without the article you linked. You helped me and I learned a lot of that article so you deserve to have the answer accepted.